# My jar can't find my images in my game but in the ide (eclipse) works just fine

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception, javax.imageio

so my jar can't find the images in my program but they are found by the IDE
here is the error message. I also went into the jar and they are in the jar itself , the images are all there

```
     javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
    at tile.TileManager.getTileImage(TileManager.java:53)
    at tile.TileManager.<init>(TileManager.java:35)
    at Main.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:44)
    at Main.DriverMain.main(DriverMain.java:27)
```

here is the code that makes the images

```
                idle = ImageIO.read(new File("sprites/player/mario_idle.gif"));
        walk1 = ImageIO.read(new File("sprites/player/mario_walk1.gif"));
        walk2 = ImageIO.read(new File("sprite/player/mario_walk2.gif"));
```

I also tried

```
idle = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sprites/player/mario_idle.gif"));
walk1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sprites/player/mario_walk1.gif"));
walk2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sprite/player/mario_walk2.gif"));
```

but I get a null pointer exception ^

my file structure are as follows

project folder > src > packages( entity , main, sprites , tile) > in spites are 2 folders player and map which houses the png's or gifs

again if I zip the jar and look inside it I can see the sprites folder and when i open it all the images are there

I tried having the images in an upper package "res" outside of  src and it still gave me the same thing but this time the images where not inside the jar , therefore I took it as it should be in src

I appreciate any help

Comment: Files don't exist within a jar -- resources do. Get your image as a resource.

Comment: See the Swing tutorial on: [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Comment: Thanks, totally figured it out  
this is my first time dealing with jars and now I know